# How do I filter .csv file before reading

Tags: r, csv, filter, import

I want to work with a filtered subset of my dataset.

Example: healthstats.csv

```
    age   weight   height   gender
A    25      150      65      female
B    24      175      78      male
C    26      130      72      male
D    32      200      69      female
E    28      156      66      male
F    40      112      78      female
```

I would start with

```
patients = read.csv("healthstats.csv")
```

but how to I only import a subset of

```
patients$gender == "female"
```

when I run

```
patients = read.csv("healthstats.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to import only a subset of rows without reading them you can use `sqldf` which accepts a query to filter data.

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("healthstats.csv", sql = "select * from file where gender == 'female'")
```

---

We can also use `read_csv_chunked` from `readr`

```
readr::read_csv_chunked('healthstats.csv', 
  callback = DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, pos) subset(x, gender == "female")))
```