# Working with large CSV file using duckdb or arrow in R

Tags: r, database, duckdb

I know nothing about databases nor duckdb nor arrow---hence the struggle, likely.
I have a large CSV file (7.5 GB) on my hard drive. In R, without loading it into my memory, I want to:

1. Extract column names
2. Select a subset of columns and rows

And then load this subset dataset into R.

How can I do this? I am struggling to understand how to do this based on what I found online.

Comment: You can select columns and number of rows when reading in, for example: `data.table:fread("myfile.txt", select = 1:3, nrows = 10)`

Comment: Does it not read the whole CSV file first? If it does not, it could work for the columns but not for filtering based on conditions, it seems

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/58296934/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63134876/680068

Comment: nrows argument will read only specified number of to we, not a whole file. For filtering rows use grep.

Comment: In comments you mention you have several csv files, is it by any chance a partitioned dataset where directory structure is based on some variables like years and/or months, `2023/01/file.csv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(duckdb, arrow, dbplyr)
  
path_to_csv <- "c:/path/to/file.csv"

# Create a database from one local csv file (does not upload the data)
database <- arrow::open_dataset(source = path_to_csv, format = "csv") %>%
   arrow::to_duckdb()

# Final dataset
clean_loaded_data <- database %>%
   select(column_1) %>%
   filter(item %in% list) %>%
   collect()
```

Where `collect()` instructs R to upload the subset dataset into the environment. The source argument can also be a list of .csv files.

Comment: This looks like an even simpler / more efficient solution.

Comment: Selected my answer as it is less verbose and uses dplyr syntax, which I am more familiar with compared to SQL-type syntax. Not sure if there is a performance difference between Karten's solution and mine.

Answer (score 3):

If there is enough space on the hard disk, I would import the csv into a duckdb file using

```
library(duckdb)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "your.duckdb") # creates an empty file 'your.duckdb'
duckdb::duckdb_read_csv(con, "your_tbl", "your_1.csv") # populates db from csv
duckdb::duckdb_read_csv(con, "your_tbl", "your_2.csv") # append to the existing data
```

`duckdb_read_csv` is really fast and uses multithreading I believe.

Now you can use SQL to get information on the columns, e.g.

```
stmt <- paste0(
    "SELECT column_name, data_type FROM ",
    "information_schema.columns WHERE ",
    "table_name = 'your_tbl';"
)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, stmt)
```

and to select your rows, e.g.

```
stmt <- paste0(
   "SELECT your_col1, your_col2 FROM your_tbl ",
   "WHERE your_col3>0;"
)
dat <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, stmt)
```

Don't forget to disconnect after use, e.g.

```
DBI::dbDisconnect(con, shutdown=TRUE)
```

EDIT:
"Tbh I have several large CSV that I need to filter all at once, do you reckon I could create a database with all of them (whatever that means) and do a massive select and filter exercise at once?"

You could either call `duckdb::duckdb_read_csv` for each csv and perform the filtering afterwards. You would simply call `duckdb_read_csv` several times with the same `con` and `name` argument. Note that the structure of the CSVs (number, names, and types of the columns) needs to be the same.

Or otherwise, if disk space is an issue, you could also read in one csv, and then perform the filtering as deletion inside the duckdb:

```
stmt <- paste0("DELETE FROM your_tbl WHERE your_col3>0;")
DBI::dbExecute(con, stmt)
```

Then you would read in the next csv. When all CSV are read, you could call `dbReadTable` to get the required data set:

```
dat <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, "your_tbl")
```

Comment: This approach seems great. I'm just missing a step. In line 2 of your code, you seem to be assuming that I have a .duckbd file, which I don't and don't know how to create. Could you explain that step better? Mind that I have been doing data analysis and statistical inference for years but do not know the first thing about databases. Tbh I have several large CSV that I need to filter all at once, do you reckon I could create a database with all of them (whatever that means) and do a massive select and filter exercise at once? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: I will try to implement your approach again and see if it's faster than the one I suggested. I will award the answer based on that. In any case, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

@Karsten has the correct answer if you use duckdb. To answer your question about a needing ".duckdb" file, you don't actually need one, duckdb will create one for you. I would recommend it so DuckDB has a place to store temporary data when parsing your CSV. You can just delete the .duckdb file afterwards

Another option for getting column info would be

```
columns = DBI::dbGetQuery("Describe read_csv_auto('path/to/file.csv')")
```

If you want to persist your selected data, you can write it to a new csv file or to a duckdb file

Copy to csv

```
stmt <- paste0(
    "COPY (SELECT your_col1, your_col2 FROM your_tbl ",
    "WHERE your_col3>0;) to 'my_csv_file.csv' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER 1);"
)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, stmt)
```

If you want to persist it to a duckdb file, then you need to pass a filename to the connection.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "persistent_db.duckdb")
...
stmt <- paste0(
    "Create table my_table as (SELECT column_name, data_type FROM ",
    "information_schema.columns WHERE ",
    "table_name = 'your_tbl');"
)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, stmt)
```

This duckdb file will be (probably much) smaller than a csv file, but won't be human readable. You will need to connect to it again using duckdb to read it back.

I would reply directly to the comment, but I don't have enough reputation.